# xskak manual page 36 - diagram below printing of moves

Tags: chess, chessboard, xskak

Last nite, I saw a german chess book with a diagram after every 5 moves. The 1st five moves were shown, then followed by a diagram.

Following Ulrike Fischer's feedback, I added her code. When I compare the manual against mine, the result is different.

Any idea why? Is there a better way of doing it? It's the same process repeated 3 different times. Can I do it in a loop?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{skak, xskak,chessboard}
\begin{document}
\newchessgame

\hidemoves{
1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 d6 3.d4 Bg4 4.dxe5 Bxf3 5.Qxf3 dxe5 6.Bc4 Nf6 7.Qb3 Qe7 8.Nc3 c6 9.Bg5 b5 10.Nxb5 cxb5 11.Bxb5+ Nbd7 12.O-O-O Rd8 13.Rxd7 Rxd7 14.Rd1 Qe6 15.Bxd7+ Nxd7 16.Qb8+ Nxb8 17.Rd8#}
\\
% *** how to print out diagram at certain number move pg 36?
\noindent
\xskakloop[step=10,showlast]{%
\begin{tabular}{c}
\chessboard[tinyboard,
setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]
\\
\xskakget{opennr}\xskakget{lan}%
\end{tabular}\quad}%
\\

% *** how to put diagram under each of these set of moves?
\printchessgame[style=UF,level=1,initmoveid=1w,stopmoveid=5b]

\xskakset{moveid=5b}\chessboard[smallboard,setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]

\printchessgame[style=UF,level=1,initmoveid=6w,stopmoveid=10b]

\xskakset{moveid=10w}\chessboard[smallboard,setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]

\printchessgame[style=UF,level=1,initmoveid=11w,stopmoveid=15b]

\xskakset{moveid=15b}\chessboard[smallboard,setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]

\printchessgame[style=UF,level=1,initmoveid=16w,stopmoveid=17w]

\xskakset{moveid=17w}\chessboard[smallboard,setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Simply write `\xskakset{moveid=5b}\chessboard[setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]` in the place where you want the diagram (with the correct move number)

Comment: Don't edit a question for follow-up questions. You can't expect people to keep track of such edits. And don't ask to many questions in one post. I will answer one of your questions here.

Comment: Sorry about that. I was trying to edit my codes and I thought I can combine them together. I will take your advice. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are repetitions you can always build loops. Beside the inbuild \xskakloop-command you can also use all other loop commands provided by tex packages. Here an example with a \foreach loop.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\begin{document}
\newchessgame

\hidemoves{
1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 d6 3.d4 Bg4 4.dxe5 Bxf3 5.Qxf3 dxe5 6.Bc4 Nf6 7.Qb3 Qe7 8.Nc3 c6 9.Bg5 b5 10.Nxb5 cxb5 11.Bxb5+ Nbd7 12.O-O-O Rd8 13.Rxd7 Rxd7 14.Rd1 Qe6 15.Bxd7+ Nxd7 16.Qb8+ Nxb8 17.Rd8#}

% *** how to put diagram under each of these set of moves?
\foreach \x/\y in {1w/5b,6w/10b,11w/15b,16w/17w}
{
 \par
 \printchessgame[style=UF,level=1,initmoveid=\x,stopmoveid=\y]
 \par
 \xskakset{moveid=\y}\chessboard[smallboard,setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]
} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. I am in awe with the features of tex. Thank you so much for teaching me.